Animate Transition Between Column and Row Layout
Is there a way to display a set of children as a Row, then toggle to a column layout and have the children physically move to their new position (and back to a Row if toggled). I don't want functionality of the AnimatedCrossFade widget, as this makes the children fade to their new position, but instead animate similar to an AnimatedPosition.
